# Sencha cmd dev build output with unbundled files

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I wasn't able to find any docs regarding this one but I want to have a build output from the sencha app build development command of unbundled files from my packages. Btw, I am using a universalclassicmodern app.

Basically, it's like the same build output when building in production but its files are not bundled into a single js file.

I am trying this now and change the location of my build output, one of the problems I encountered is that the ext framework was referenced to the node_modules inside my application directory causing it to throw not file found errors on the browser console.

Is it possible to do this? What exact configurations do I need to change in my `app.json`?

EDIT:
Current app.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "namespace": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "framework": "ext",
  "template": "universalclassicmodern",
  "indexHtmlPath": "../../index.html",
  "requires": [],

  "builds": {
    "desktop": {
      "toolkit": "classic",
      "theme": "MyTheme",
      "requires": [],
      "uses": ["Package1", "Package2"],
      "sass": {
        "generated": {
          "var": "${build.id}/sass/save.scss",
          "src": "${build.id}/sass/save"
        }
      }
    },
    "phone": {
      "toolkit": "modern",
      "theme": "theme-material",
      "requires": [],
      "sass": {
        "generated": {
          "var": "${build.id}/sass/save.scss",
          "src": "${build.id}/sass/save"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "classpath": ["app/shared/src", "app/${build.id}/src"],
  "overrides": ["app/shared/overrides", "app/${build.id}/overrides"],

  "sass": {
    "namespace": "MyApp",
    "etc": ["sass/etc/all.scss"],
    "var": ["app/shared/sass/var.scss", "app/${build.id}/sass/var.scss"],
    "src": ["app/shared/src/sass/src.scss", "app/${build.id}/sass/src.scss"]
  },

  "resources": [
    { "path": "resources", "output": "shared" },
    { "path": "resources/${build.id}" }
  ],

  "output": {
    "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
    "page": "index.html",
    "manifest": "generatedFiles/${build.id}.json",
    "js": "generatedFiles/${build.id}/app.js",
    "appCache": { "enable": false },
    "resources": {
      "path": "${build.id}/resources",
      "shared": "resources"
    }
  },

  "fashion": {
    "missingParameters": "error",
    "inliner": { "enable": false }
  },

  "js": [],
  "css": [
    {
      "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
      "bundle": true,
      "exclude": ["fashion"]
    }
  ],

  "loader": {
    "cache": false,
    "cacheParam": "_dc"
  },

  "production": {
    "js": [{ "path": "app.js", "bundle": true }],
    "output": {
      "base": "Dir\\build/${build.environment}",
      "page": {
        "path": "../../index.html",
        "enable": false
      },
      "appCache": {
        "enable": false,
        "path": "cache.appcache"
      },
      "manifest": {
        "path": "generatedFiles/${build.id}.json"
      },
      "microloader": {
        "path": "generatedFiles/bootstrap.js"
      }
    },
    "loader": {
      "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
    },
    "cache": {
      "enable": true
    },
    "compressor": {
      "type": "yui"
    }
  },

  "testing": {},

  "development": {
    "output": {
      "base": "DIR\\build/${build.environment}/",
      "page": {
        "path": "../../index.html",
        "enable": false
      },
      "appCache": {
        "enable": false,
        "path": "cache.appcache"
      },
      "js": "generatedFiles/${build.id}/app.js"
    },
    "js": [
      { "path": "ext-7.3.0/build/ext-all-debug.js" },
      { "path": "app.js", "bundle": true },
      { "path": "main.js" }
    ],
    "watch": {
      "delay": 250
    }
  },

  "bootstrap": {
    "base": "DIR\\build/${build.environment}/",
    "manifest": {
      "path": "generatedFiles/${build.id}.json",
      "exclude": "loadOrder"
    },
    "microloader": "generatedFiles/bootstrap.js",
    "css": "generatedFiles/bootstrap.css"
  },

  "cache": {
    "enable": false,
    "deltas": "${build.id}/deltas"
  },

  "appCache": {
    "cache": ["index.html"],
    "network": ["*"],
    "fallback": []
  },

  "archivePath": "archive/${build.id}",

  "ignore": ["(^|/)CVS(/?$|/.*?$)"],
  "id": "3744de5b-2058-461b-8c65-6721bbe044c9"
}
```

Here's the difference of build output between dev and prod. They are more likely the same but the difference is that the production build concatenates the files on a single js file for the app and per package. What I want is the opposite.

[image: Difference of build output between dev and prod]

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem for a while until I discovered the 'testing' build.

So instead of running this command to build your app:

```
sencha app build desktop
```

Try running this command:

```
sencha app build testing
```

Then navigate to where you build directory is and you will notice a new directory named 'testing'.

Open index.html with Google Chrome and make sure the developer console is running. You should now see a lot more information to help you find which libraries have not been included.

Comment: I already tried the sencha app build testing but it bundles my .js files into one js file, especially on my packages. I am looking for a way wherein the files are separated as it was on my application's working directory. Do you happen to have any suggestions on how can I make this possible?

Comment: I realise now that I didn't read your question properly at all. I apologise for that.

As for preventing the bundling of library files, I honestly haven't tried to do that.Maybe try giving this page a scan through - there seems to be quite a lot of options for compiling and building:

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.6.0/guides/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html